# Possible to enable EditText instantly when its disabled

Tags: android

Can an editText field be enabled instantly when I call editText.setEnabled(true); ?

Currently I have a code which says:

```
toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
row1TextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.row1EditText);
row2TextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.row2EditText);

if(toggleButton.isChecked())
{
   if(row1TextField.isFocused()){

     row2TextField.setEnabled(false);
     }
}

if(!toggleButton.isChecked())
{
   if(row1TextField.isFocused()){
    row2TextField.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

With this code, the setEnabled on EditText doesn't reflect instantly though. For example is, when I switch between the states ON and OFF of my toggleButton, the Row2TextField isn't enabled/disabled automatically eventhough I'm on row1TextField on. I have to click the other EditText and go back to row1TextField in order to disable/enable it.

Is there a way I can let it reflect its state instantly instead of changing to different Focus in order to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

you should use onCheckedChangedListender for ToggleButton

and should like this

```
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){
                row1TextField.setEnabled(true);
                row2TextField.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else 
            {
                row1TextField.setEnabled(false);
                row2TextField.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

In this way, you can be enable/disable instantly.

Comment: I have to use the onFocusChange and also OnCheckedChanged together. I'm not sure if its possible to merge them together.

Comment: I think that's not problem. The case is using onFocusChange and setting enable/disable. According to the logic, you shouldn't use like that.